# How to avoid making generalizations without "some" or "such as"?

Tags: grammar, phrases

How can I avoid making a generalization below in the sentence without using "some", "such as" or "excluding" before or after the subject?

**Impressionist painters turned their attention to scenes that celebrated life.**

- Actually, not all Impressionist painters did so. There were exceptions.

Comment: "82.3% of Impressionist painters turned their attention to scenes that celebrated life."

Comment: It's not clear what you want. You could say "A number of impressionist painters turned their attention to scenes that celebrated life."

Comment: Instead of "such as X" you can say "for example X."

Comment: _Typically_ is a useful adverb for this. In a generic, you're not interested in numbers, nor in all-inclusive truth. _French people speak French_ is reasonable, even though there are exceptions.

Comment: “Most Impressionist painters....?”

Answer (score 2):

> Impressionist painters tended to depict scenes that celebrated life.
>
> Impressionist painters often turned their attention to scenes that celebrated life.
>
> Impressionist painters are known for turning their attention to scenes that celebrate life.